# Remove line break from html(php) file

Tags: php, html, split, line, break

I have already search about this question,I want to remove line break from the html,but there a some split php line in the html file,for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?='abc'?></title>
</head>
<?php
if($_SESSION['test'] == 'yes'){
echo 'hello';
}
?>
123456
43567
<?='13245tryt57u68'?>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I remove line break from this php file?

Comment: It might be worth explaining why you want to remove the line breaks. What issues are they causing? Php code isn't rendered to the browser so although you have a line break to make the file look tidy, it won't be displayed on the page.

Comment: use a better source code editor ...

Comment: what do you mean with "linebreak" here?

Comment: Do you mean "GZIP", http://www.webcodingtech.com/php/gzip-compression.php

Comment: Wheres the opening `<body>` tag?

Comment: Or you can use notepad++ with regular expression search and replace

Comment: sorry forgot the body tag..I want to make the html lighter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ob_start();`

```
<?php ob_start();
//Start page output
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?='abc';?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['test']) && $_SESSION['test'] == 'yes'){
    echo 'hello';
}
?>
123456
43567
<?='13245tryt57u68';?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
//End page output and assign the contents to a variable
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//Replace the new line with null
echo str_replace("\n",null,$buffer);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
<html><head><title>abc</title></head><body>1234564356713245tryt57u68</body></html>
```

Comment: np, tho if you have any inline javascript remember to close off every line or you may find your js dont work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in your IDE:
Use replace function, and replace \n by no character

If you want it for the client:
You have to configure your htaccess to remove the lines breaks/indenting when sending the file to the client, ie by using the mod_pagespeed extension:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/mod-pagespeed-settings/ and the collapse_whitespace option